# Unexpected behavior when searching in code

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Embarcadero® Delphi 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236

1. In the code editor, I search for some word 1 in the current unit.
2. Press the <kbd>F3</kbd> key.
3. Select some word 2 in the code (for example, by mouse double-clicking).
4. Press the <kbd>F3</kbd> key again.

Expected result: search for word 1.
Actual result: search for word 2.

Moreover, in the control of the Search panel, I see word 1. But the search continues by the last selected word in the text.

Is it a bug, or a new feature?

It really disturbs my work. How to turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Delphi 11 that was fixed in Delphi 12:

[RSP-40690: Highlight words settings seems to affect behavior of F3](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-40690)

Comment: Using the down (or up) arrow next to the search box still works, as does Ctrl-L.